# removing a trailing slash from a filename (index.php/ to index.php)

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I'm sure I'm missing a trick here but I can't work out how to remove the trailing slash from a file name in a URL using an Apache `RewriteRule`.

My URL would be something like this:

www.mysite.com/dynamic_folder_name/index.php/

I need the URL to become

www.mysite.com/dynamic_folder_name/index.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: edited your question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Where*** do you want to do this?

In an Apache rewrite rule?
In a PHP page?
In a bash script?

Plase specify...

---

### Update

RewriteRule. Ok. This should do what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, as an apache rewrite rule, so a .htaccess file

Comment: ...why the downvote?!?

Comment: hmm wasn't me :/

Comment: Because people are overzealous.  I canceled it out.

Comment: Thanks Massimo, that works perfectly...so simple.  Can't believe I missed it!

Comment: One more example of why people should have to leave a comment when down-voting (even if that comment is anonymous).

Comment: @eek, regular expressions *are* quite tricky...

Comment: Won't this rule cause a redirect loop if you try to access any directories? For example www.mysite.com/dynamic_folder_name  
It might be better to modify it to look specifically for the php extension or something similar before redirecting the trailing slash.

Comment: @matthew: no, it only removes a *trailing* slash, thus there can't be another one after having removed it; besides, the "L" flag tells pache "don't process any other rewrite rule after this one".

Comment: @Massimo the RewriteRule only says to remove the slash, but if the DirectorySlash directive is set to "ON", which is the default, it would cause them to each override the other (ie. a loop). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash